# Buffalo wireless router

Tags: wireless-router, dd-wrt, buffalo-router

I have a Buffalo wireless router and it appears to work fine, for the most part.  However, printing out some debug information, I noticed that the Mode is reported as unknown/bug.

In the DD-WRT configuration, I have selected AP which should be Master.  I was having a problem earlier with my ESSID being a bunch of weird characters.  I re-entered it and restarted the router and now the ESSID is correct.

I tried re-entering the configuration for the router and it still is reported back as Unknown/bug via iwlist wlan0 scanning.

Any ideas?

Walter

Comment: What model is the router? If it's a Broadcom SoC, you might just need to do a 30-30-30 "hard reset" to clear your nvram.

Comment: It is the n-finiti: wzr-hp-ag300h

Comment: I tried a hard-reset, I am still having the same problem.  I believe that is why some devices do not see the router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that the build 14998 has some issues with my particular device.  There are several fixes:

1. either upgrade to the latest firmware which is greater than 15672.
2. do not run the power kernel on the n900.
3. upgrade the power kernel to fix an issue with seeing dd-wrt routers.

Walter